# Plotting cosine wave samples in Maple

Tags: plot, maple

I'm having trouble with Maple.

I have a cosine wave, which I figured out how to plot, but now I have to take samples
from that wave and plot those(as dots) over top of the original cosine wave.
Here is the question from the assignment:

***"Produce the samples from Q1 above and plot the result (plot the points on a plot of the cosine wave - use different colours for both, it will look like a cosine wave with dots on it)"***

Problem is, my samples keep being straight lines at different heights

[image]

http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa221/Haseo_Ame/Maple.png

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I've never used maple before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try not to build up lists using repeated concatenation (which can incur an O(n^2) in resources) if you can use the `seq` command instead (which can incur an O(n) cost in resources). You should always reconsider, when coding like `s:=[op(s),...]` in a loop.

Next, a point-plot needs pairs of x-y values. Your list is just a collection of scalar values, and hence is being interpreted as a collection of constant functions to be plotted.

The pairs of x-y values can be in a list of (2-element) lists such as `[[x1,y1],...,[xn,yn]`

It's not clear how you want your x-axis scaled, but you could start off with something like this,

```
s:=[seq([i, 4*cos(2*Pi*i*70/200+Pi/4)],i=0..20)]:

plot(s, style=point);
```

[image]

```
#  s:=[seq([2*Pi*i*70/200+Pi/4, 4*cos(2*Pi*i*70/200+Pi/4)],i=0..20)]:
```

ps. Please post source code as text, not as embedded images, so that anyone trying to help needn't type it all in.

Comment: Thank you; it took a bit of working out, but I think I got it.
Sorry about not posting the code as text, I'm still figuring out 
the posting system here.